# Error installing mercurial on linux: unable to generate hg.mo

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to install mercurial from source. I tried installing mercurial version 3.5 and 3.6 from here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/

My Linux version: **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)**

and my python version: **Python 2.6.5**

This is the error I get when I try to built it locally.

```
make local
python setup.py  \
   build_py -c -d . \
   build_ext  -i \
   build_hgexe  -i \
   build_mo
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_hgexe
running build_mo
generating mercurial/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/hg.mo from i18n/zh_TW.po
msgfmt -v -o mercurial/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/hg.mo i18n/zh_TW.po -c
usage: msgfmt [ -dv ] [ - ] [ name ... ]
mercurial/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/hg.mo: No such file or directory
error: command 'msgfmt' failed with exit status 2
 make: *** [local] Error 1
```

Comment: Looks like you have a `msgfmt` in your PATH that isn't the one that the installer expects to find.  Do `which msgfmt` and if the result isn't `/usr/bin/msgfmt` that's probably the cause.

Comment: That was it, thanks very much. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a `msgfmt` in your `PATH` that isn't the one that the installer expects to find.

Do:

```
which msgfmt
```

and if the result isn't `/usr/bin/msgfmt` that's probably the cause